# In "R" during plotting "tmap" library places labels outside plotting region (partially)

Tags: r, tmap

I am importing shapefile into R and try to plot it with labels. Unfortunately some labels overlap. That's why I have to use parameter "**auto.placement = T**" for the "**tm_text**" function. But this parameter places some labels outside plotting region (partially). Position of labels on every plot is random. Sometimes labels are withing plotting region, but most of the times are not (cutted).

As you can see on screenshot "Palangos m." is cutted down to "angos m." and "Klaipedos m." is cutted down to "aipedos m.".

**Screenshot**: [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjUTq.png)

```
tm_shape(area_r1) + 
  tm_fill("winner", title = "Winner", style = "cat", 
      palette = c("#FFFFB3", "#1F78B4", "#1A9850", "#E7298A") ) +
  tm_legend(text.size = 0.75) +
  tm_layout("", legend.position = c("left", "bottom")) +
  tm_borders("grey60") +
  tm_layout(frame = F) +
  tm_text("savivald", size = .65, col = "black", auto.placement = T)
```

What can I do in order to fit this labels into plotting region?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controlling the randomness of `auto.placement = T` is difficult (though setting seed may help).

What you *can* do is adjusting the bounding box of your `tmap` object oh so slightly, so that there is more room on the left for the two or so missing letters.

Increasing the bbox by a half is probably an exaggeration, but you can tune it as required.

```
bbox_new <- st_bbox(area_r1) # current bounding box

xrange <- bbox_new$xmax - bbox_new$xmin # range of x values
yrange <- bbox_new$ymax - bbox_new$ymin # range of y values

  bbox_new[1] <- bbox_new[1] - (0.5 * xrange) # xmin - left
# bbox_new[3] <- bbox_new[3] + (0.5 * xrange) # xmax - right
# bbox_new[2] <- bbox_new[2] - (0.5 * yrange) # ymin - bottom
# bbox_new[4] <- bbox_new[4] + (0.5 * yrange) # ymax - top

bbox_new <- bbox_new %>%  # take the bounding box ...
  st_as_sfc() # ... and make it a sf polygon

tm_shape(area_r1, bbox = bbox_new) + 
  tm_fill("winner", title = "Winner", style = "cat", 
      palette = c("#FFFFB3", "#1F78B4", "#1A9850", "#E7298A") ) +
  tm_legend(text.size = 0.75) +
  tm_layout("", legend.position = c("left", "bottom")) +
  tm_borders("grey60") +
  tm_layout(frame = F) +
  tm_text("savivald", size = .65, col = "black", auto.placement = T)
```

I wrote a blog post summarizing the technique a while back. https://www.jla-data.net/eng/adjusting-bounding-box-of-a-tmap-map/

Your example is not exactly reproducible, but this image (making more space for the "big fat, title" on North Carolina map) should give you idea.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Looks like it solves problem.Interestingly, that it also shifted legend to the left (relative to unaltered plot at the bottom). Take a look: https://ibb.co/mzjPds3

Comment: @Helios This is to be expected, as the legend is locked to bottom left and you created more space to the left of your map. In fact accommodating big legends and titles was my original problem :)

Answer (score 0):

@Jinda Lacko has a creative solution using `bbox` , but for some reason it did not work for me. An easy solution is to use `main.title` in `tm_layout`, for example `tm_layout(main.title = "Big Fat Title")`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355422/how-to-put-title-of-a-map-outside-of-the-panel-tmap-package) for more details.