# How to put title of a map outside of the panel (tmap package)

Tags: r, tmap

I'm plotting a simple map in R and I'm stuck with this problem: the title is overlapping the plot and I don't know how to put it outside of the panel.

[image: brasil]

With ggplot2 I can do this easily with `plot.title.position` option in `theme` function, since tmap works with the same logic, I think might be a way to do this.

Code and [shapefile download](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2018/Brasil/BR/BR.zip):

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

brasil <- st_read("/shp/BRUFE250GC_SIR.shp")

tm_shape(brasil) +
    tm_borders() +
    tm_fill() +
    tm_compass() +
    tm_scale_bar() +
    tm_layout(
        title = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    )
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `tm_layout(main.title = "Main Title", main.title.position = "center")` in place of `tm_layout(title = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")` to have the title outside the map.

```
tm_shape(brasil) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_fill() +
  tm_compass() +
  tm_scale_bar() +
  tm_layout(
    main.title = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", 
    main.title.position = "center")
```

[image]